# Why is the sort pointer in the lightning datatable always pointing downwards in my case?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, sort

Here is the code for my sorting method and it works great:

```
sort : function(component, event, helper) {
    let sortedBy = event.getParam('fieldName');
    let sortedField = (component.get('v.sortedBy'));
    let sortDirection = component.get('v.sortDirection');;
        let contacts = component.get('v.contacts');
        let cloneContacts = contacts.slice(0);
            sortDirection = sortedField != sortedBy || !sortDirection;
            cloneContacts.sort(function(a,b){
            var t1 = a[sortedBy] == b[sortedBy],
            t2 = (!a[sortedBy] && b[sortedBy]) || (a[sortedBy] < b[sortedBy]);
            return t1? 0: (sortDirection?-1:1)*(t2?1:-1);
    });
        component.set('v.contacts', cloneContacts);
        component.set('v.sortDirection', sortDirection);
        component.set('v.sortedBy', sortedBy);
        component.set('v.sortedOn', true);
        helper.getDisplayDataPagination(component);
```

}

But there is one caveat: the pointer that displays the sorting direction (as I understand it) is always directed downwards, but should change (up / down). How to fix it? Because I'm a beginner, then I admit that I missed some obvious thing ...

[image]
[image]

**// cmp**

```
...
    <aura:attribute name="sortedBy" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortDirection" type="Boolean"/>
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
...
```

**//js**

```
init : function (component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.columns', [
       { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'URL', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'Name'}, target: '_self' },sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Contact Level', fieldName: 'Contact_Level__c', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Account', fieldName: 'AccountName', type: 'text', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Owner', fieldName: 'OwnerName', type: 'text', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Created By', fieldName: 'CreatedByName', type: 'text', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Created Date', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date', sortable: true  },
    ]);
    helper.getDataFromDB(component, helper);
},
```

Comment: Are you actually setting the sort direction on the datatable (are you binding it)?

Answer (score 4):

The [Datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDatatableSorting) documentation actually has an example specific to sorting you'll find helpful.

Taking a quick look, I'd use the parameter in the click event to get the sort direction versus trying to calculate as you've attempted (unless you have some other need I'm not catching).

```
var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
component.set("v.sortDirection",sortDirection);
```

In terms of your exact code, I believe the valid values are `asc` or `desc` for sortedDirection. You can check the [specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/specification) for that information.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I had an example like in the documentation, but I don't like how it works with my table data. Then I implemented my current sort, which works great and works for me. Could you help me with editing my variation but using 'asc' and 'desc'? I am a newbie and I can't get it ...

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could share the .cmp code as well so I can see what types the attributes are

Comment: I edited my question and tried to add all the necessary information.

Comment: If you just use a different `string` attribute and use what the documentation says `component.set("v.sortDirectionString",event.getParam('sortDirection');`, you can still keep your sorting mechanism. The `sortedDirection`in lightning:datatable` just controls the up or down arrow icon that displays.